# Terminal showing “^[OA” when up arrow (↑) is pressed

Tags: terminal

The up arrow in the terminal should bring up the previous command. My terminal (including iTerm2 and Intellij IDEA terminal) shows `^[OA` when I press the up arrow (<kbd>↑</kbd>).

If I press return, the previous command is still executed. It works fine and I can see the command if I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> first.

Comment: I'm also finding this. Did you figure out why?

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: Same issue, it is fixed after i run `reset`, still searching what is causing the switch on the generated codes.

Comment: any permanent solution found? :(